# "error: attempt to read or write outside of 'hd0' press any key to continue"

Tags: 14.04

I use Ubuntu 14.04 LTS and my laptop is a Dell XPS L502X.

My laptop has stopped working, when I start it up I get this

```
error:attempt to read or write outside of 'hd0'
press any key to continue...
```

I know for a fact that during boot I can repeatedly tap the <kbd>esc</kbd> to get into the grubloader and from there press 'c' to get into a command line screen

If I do 'ls' it shows (hd0) (hd0,msdos5) (hd0,msdos1)

How do I fix this?

EDIT: this is the output of `df --human`

`ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ df --human
df: ‘/var/lib/polkit-1/localauthority/90-mandatory.d’: Permission denied
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/cow            3.9G  443M  3.5G  12% /
/dev            3.9G   12K  3.9G   1% /mnt/dev
tmpfs           788M  1.2M  787M   1% /run
/dev/sdb1       7.2G  980M  6.3G  14% /cdrom
/dev/loop0      939M  939M     0 100% /rofs
none            4.0K     0  4.0K   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
tmpfs           3.9G  9.0M  3.9G   1% /tmp
none            5.0M  4.0K  5.0M   1% /run/lock
none            3.9G  516K  3.9G   1% /run/shm
none            100M   60K  100M   1% /run/user
/dev/sda1       909G   13G  851G   2% /mnt`

Comment: boot using a live CD and do a `sudo parted --list`, mount all local drives and do a `df --human` and post the output to your question.

Comment: Ok, Ill get onto that asap, and see what I can do.

Comment: Well I have done the `df --human` command and the output is where the question is, what to do now?

Comment: Whew!  Could you also post /etc/fstab?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by posting `/etc/fstab` (Any mounting involved?)

Comment: Oh yeah and when I try to copy something from my computer during a live cd session it says that I don't have the correct permissions to perform that action, if I right-click on that, go into properties and then click permissions, the read and write attributes are set only to "User #1000", how can I fix this?

Comment: Is this a fresh install?  Only 2% of your 900GB drive seems to be used... and the `fstab` file should be at `/mnt/etc/fstab` in the liveCD  (I thought your drive would be full, but that's not the case)

Comment: No, I installed Ubuntu a few months ago, but managed not to install/download so much stuff to my HDD. Ill see what I can do about `/mnt/etc/fstab`.

Comment: Oh yeah and what is it with file permissions? I can't copy anything because I don't have the permissions to do that, it is set to user #1000

Comment: EDIT: I fixed the file permissions thing and I backed up my stuff, I'm considering doing a fresh install, but if I can rescue my system I will do whatever possible as long as I know it will work. And btw thanks for responding, it's nice to know I have some help on my side.

Comment: User 1000 is the first user you define on your system.  root should still have access to everything.  So if you want to copy files (and you have a standard install and want to use the standard file manager) start it by `sudo nautilus` and then do the copying

Comment: I'm in a different time zone now, so I think the best you can do is reinstall.  (unless we can take this up in chat). Drop me a note @Fabby when you're on-line.  If I haven't seen anything by the time I'm done with Ask Ubuntu, I'll post an answer that'll help you for the future...

Answer (score 0):

As the backup of your data succeeded, to avoid this in the future ensure that you have 2 backups: an off-line system back-up and an on-line data backup.

To be able to even make a system backup, you need to install Ubuntu with *at least* 3 partitions: `swap`, `/` and `/home` and have an additional HDD (preferably external, so you can store it away from the computer)

**To make a system back-up**, boot a [CloneZilla](http://clonezilla.org) live CD, back-up `/` as a disk-to-image and keep *at least* the current and the previous copy (so that if the system crashes *during* the system back-up, you still have your previous one)

**To restore a system backup**, boot a live CD (preferably just the [gparted Live CD](http://gparted.org/livecd.php) as it boots quickest) delete the swap and system partition and re-create them.  Then restore the system backup with a CloneZilla restore image-to-disk.

**How often should you make a system backup?** Before you do anything drastic, like upgrading your main application, or after you've done some major tinkering. I do that every couple of months (sometimes weeks)

**To make a data back-up**: continue using your current back-up program but use that to backup `/home` only...